# Use awk to parse and modify every CSV field

Tags: parsing, awk, field

I need to parse and modify a each field from a CSV header line for a dynamic sqlite create table statement.  Below is what works from the command line with the appropriate output:

```
echo ",header1,header2,header3"| awk 'BEGIN {FS=","}; {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){printf ",%s text ", $i}; printf "\n"}' 
,header1 text ,header2 text ,header3 text
```

Well, it breaks when it is run from within a bash shell script. I got it to work by writing the output to a file like below:

```
echo $optionalHeaders | awk 'BEGIN {FS=","}; {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){printf ",%s text ", $i}; printf "\n"}' > optionalHeaders.txt
```

This sucks!  There are a lot of examples that show how to parse/modify specific Nth fields.  This issue requires each field to be modified.  Is there a more concise and elegant Awk one liner that can store its contents to a variable rather than writing to a file?

Comment: try to put double quotes for your variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed is usually the right tool for simple substitutions on a single line. Take your pick:

```
$ echo ",header1,header2,header3"  | sed 's/[^,][^,]*/& text/g'
,header1 text,header2 text,header3 text

$ echo ",header1,header2,header3"  | sed -r 's/[^,]+/& text/g'
,header1 text,header2 text,header3 text
```

The last 1 above requires GNU sed to use EREs instead of BREs. You can do the same in awk using `gsub()` if you prefer:

```
$ echo ",header1,header2,header3"  | awk '{gsub(/[^,]+/,"& text")}1'
,header1 text,header2 text,header3 text
```

Comment: Wow, This is where it pays to make a mistake.  This was very educational and will be handy going forward.  I chose Ed Morton's  sed simplifications.  It makes perfect sense and is very concise.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and it was me...  I forgot to echo the contents of the variable to the Awk command.  Brianadams comment was so simple that forced me to re-look at my code and find the problem!  Thanks!

I am ok with resolving this but if anyone wants to propose a more concise and elegant Awk one liner - that would be cool.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
#! /bin/bash

header=",header1,header2,header3"
newhead=$(awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}; {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) $i=$i" text"}1' <<<"$header") 
echo "$newhead"
```

with output:

```
,header1 text,header2 text,header3 text
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying fields one by one, another option is with a simple substitution:

```
echo ",header1,header2,header3" | awk '{gsub(/[^,]+/, "& text", $0); print}'
```

That is, replace a sequence of non-comma characters with `text` appended.

Another alternative would be replacing the commas, but due to the irregularities of your header line (first comma must be left alone, no comma at the end), that's a bit less easy:

```
echo ",header1,header2,header3" | awk '{gsub(/,/, " text,", $0); sub(/^ text,/, "", $0); print $0 " text"}'
```

Btw, the rough equivalent of the two commands in `sed`:

```
echo ",header1,header2,header3" | sed -e 's/[^,]\{1,\}/& text/g'
echo ",header1,header2,header3" | sed -e 's/\(.\),/\1 text,/g' -e 's/$/ text/'
```